# I have a class in Python with getters and setters that I want to translate to MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, class, setter, getter

How could I translate this code to MATLAB? Even if I use getters and setters then how can I call the getter function in MATLAB in a latter function?

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self._temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        return self._temperature

    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        self._temperature = value
```

Comment: There's little reason to use getters and setters that don't do anything except provide direct access to an attribute. Get rid of them, and rename `_temperature` to `temperature`. That should make it easier to convert to MatLab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define setters or getters for properties in MATLAB. The conversion of your class in MATLAB would look like below:

```matlab
classdef Celsius
    properties
        temperature = 0
    end
    methods
        function obj = Celsius(temperature)
            if nargin < 1
                return
            end
            obj.temperature = temperature;
        end

        function val = toFahrenheit(obj)
            val = obj.temperature * 1.8 + 32;
        end
    end
end
```

If you wish to hide the getter of the properties, you can add an `GetAccess` attribute:

```matlab
    properties (GetAccess = private) % or `SetAccess = private` to hide the setter, and `Access = private` to hide both the setter and getter
        temperature = 0
    end
```

To use the class:

```matlab
myCelsiusObject = Celsius(); % initialise the object with temperature = 0.
myCelsiusObject = celsius(10); % initiliase the object with temperature = 10.
currentTemperature = myCelsiusObject.temperature; % get the value of the temperature property.
currentFahrenheit = myCelsiusObject.toFahrenheit; % get fahrenheit.
myCelsiusObject.temperature = 1; % set the value of the temperature property to 1.
```

---

### More on getters and setters in MATLAB

MATLAB does have getters but they are used as for so-called `Dependent` properties whose value is calculated automatically in the getter function. More on this see [this documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-get-methods.html).

Setters in MATLAB can be used on public properties for validating the input value. See [this documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-a-set-get-interface-for-properties.html)

I would also recommend you to read the [full documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html) if you intend to do more on object-oriented programming in MATLAB.